# ¿Como restar campos calculados Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

explico, necesito realizar una resta para el total, en este caso el total es la sumatoria de subtotal - la sumatoria de total_descuento que viene de PurchaseOrderLine, pero no logro poder hacerlo, necesito hacer la resta en el modelo de PurchaseRequest. La sumatoria de subtotal y total descuento la realiza correctamente.

**PurchaseRequest y PurchaseOrderLine son modelos diferentes**

**Serializador PurchaseRequest**

```
class PurchaseRequestListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subtotal = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    total_descuento = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    total= serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    def get_subtotal(self, obj):
        return obj.purchase_request_order_line.aggregate(Sum("subtotal"))

    def get_total_descuento(self, obj):
        return obj.purchase_request_order_line.aggregate(Sum("total_descuento"))
    
    # Calculo del total
    def get_total(self,obj):
        return get_subtotal() - get_total_descuento() ????
```

**Modelo PurchaseOrderLine**

```
class PurchaseOrderLine(BaseModel):
    purchase_request = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseRequest, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, verbose_name="Orden de pedido", related_name="purchase_request_order_line")
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Precio")
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Cantidad")
    descuento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Descuento", validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Subtotal")
    total_descuento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Total descuento")
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Total")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_subtotal(self):
        return self.cantidad * self.precio

    @property
    def get_total_descuento(self):
        return self.cantidad * self.precio * self.descuento/100
    
    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.subtotal - self.total_descuento


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.subtotal = self.get_subtotal
        self.total_descuento = self.get_total_descuento
        self.total = self.get_total
        super(PurchaseOrderLine, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Gracias, cualquier ayuda sera apreciada.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo resolvi haciendo esto, por si alguien tiene la misma pregunta.

```
def get_total(self, obj):
        return obj.purchase_request_order_line.aggregate(Total=(Sum('subtotal')) - Sum('total_descuento'))
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).